# Azure App Center Data SDK multiple models issue

Tags: android, visual-studio, azure, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I am using App Center's Data SDK with Xamarin Forms. I've got two models Banks & Payment Methods. I am allowing the user to create new objects of both & saving them in App Center's Data using the following methods:

```
var result = await Data.CreateAsync(newBank.Id.ToString(), newBank, DefaultPartitions.UserDocuments);
var result = await Data.CreateAsync(newMethod.Id.ToString(), newMethod, DefaultPartitions.UserDocuments);
```

Where newBank is of type Bank & newMethod is of type Payment Method.

When I retrive banks though, I get a list of all documents, including ones for payment methods. 
This is how I am retrieving them.

```
var banks = await Data.ListAsync<Bank>(DefaultPartitions.UserDocuments);
```

Similarly, while retrieving PaymentMethods, I am getting the bank's objects too.

```
var methods = await Data.ListAsync<PaymentMethods>(DefaultPartitions.UserDocuments);
```

Do you spot something wrong I am doing here? I can not see it?

Any help is appreciated in this. Thank you.

Regards
ST

Comment: what are the definitions of Bank and PaymentMethod?

Comment: These are both POCO models with 2 properties each. Bank has Name & Notes and PaymentMethod has Type & Notes where Type is an Enum

Answer (score 0):

For now, I was able to resolve it using the ClassType property as mentioned in the blog below. https://mikecodes.net/2019/06/18/digging-into-app-center-data/

Let me know if there is a better way to handle this.

Thanks 
ST